# How to align the linux output which was executed using python

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to get the output of a `bash` command to be aligned.

This is the command I am using now. I execute this bash command using python and it works fine, so I am not going to post that part.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | awk '/Completed/ {print $1}'
```

and I get this output to a variable called output

and this is it's output:

```
akamai-1576314300-xhf78         Completed                                                                                                                                                                          
akamai-1576659900-npb6g         Completed
akamai-1576746300-6vdjm         Completed
```

This is how it looks when I normally print it using `print(output)`

But I am using this output variable like this.

```
print("here is the output: "+constant.ICON+output+")
```

and my output now looks like this:

```
 - here is the output:                                                                                                                                                                                    
             ● - akamai-1576227900-wrkct               Completed
akamai-1576314300-xhf78         Completed                                                                                                                                                                          
akamai-1576400700-6m84q         Completed
akamai-1576487100-bnrg7         Completed
akamai-1576573500-g48lq         Completed
akamai-1576659900-npb6g         Completed
```

you see above after the first row, every other row should have leading white spaces to align it with the first row (the one with the black dot)

What I really want it is like this:

```
 - here is the output:                                                                                                                                                                                   
             ● - akamai-1576227900-wrkct         Completed
                 akamai-1576314300-xhf78         Completed                                                                                                                                                                          
                 akamai-1576400700-6m84q         Completed
                 akamai-1576487100-bnrg7         Completed
                 akamai-1576573500-g48lq         Completed
                 akamai-1576659900-npb6g         Completed
                 akamai-1576746300-6vdjm         Completed
```

How can I add this leading spaces?

I was thinking to take the `bash` command output to an array so I can do this properly, but I couldn't get output to an array

any good way I can do this?

Comment: What's the value of `constant.ICON`?

Comment: it is just the unicode value for an emoji

Comment: are you executing a shell command linux from python ??...that is what do you want ?

Comment: Yes exactly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help you , with subprocess you can run shell command

```
import subprocess

# cmd contains shell command
cmd='kubectl get pods -n kube-system'

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# The output from your shell command in an array
result=process.stdout.readlines()
if len(result) >= 1:
    for line in result:
        print(line.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: getting the output and printing it is not the problem, but the alignment.

Comment: @ToRrent if you try adding an line.rstrip() ?

Comment: @ToRrent we are for help us